# sql server 2005 (for old systems) and many problems for attach and restore...(changing drive location)

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, restore, detach

why sql server 2005 so sucks?

i should work on an old system that using sql server 2005!

my problems are :

1-when i detach a database and move mdf / ldf files of that db to another drive , so i can

not attach these files because of moving!

what is the best way for change the location of mdf/ldf files to another drive?

==============================================================================

2-when i backup a db that mdf/ldf of that db are on drive e , so i can not restore that bak file to another system that has not drive e / what is going on about sql server 2005 / i test this job on sql server 2008 and every thing was ok / how can i solve this issue?

i am using windows 7 ultimate / sql server management studio express edition /

thanks in future advance

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restore a database backup you need to go into the restore options and update the paths of the MDF/LDF files to wherever you want them on the new machine. The default is to keep these paths the same and obviously they may not exist on the new machine.

Comment: thanks 4 answer / bak file restore problem solved / what about detach and attach ??

Comment: I've never had a problem attaching MDF / LDF files, are they definitely from the same version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

When you did the restore, you pointed the data and log files to the new drives - you may have done this in the GUI (Management Studio) or in TSQL. When you try the reattach, you need to do the same thing - just change the file locations.

Comment: but when i detach a db and move mdf/ldf files and want to attach them again there is no option for change the location like for restore a .bak file !!!

Comment: I assume you are using the GUI - Management Studio or Enterprise Manager? It should show the file locations, and allow them to change them if you wish.

If you are using the stored procedure for attaching, I don't know off-hand if it allows you to change the file locations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you take the backup of SQL database including Log transaction files also. Then detach it by right clicking on it. Now you can change the location of MDF file and then restore. it.